# fullcalendar.js: dragging multiple events on one time

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, fullcalendar

The requirement is the following:

1. We drag element X drop it on (lets say) 19th October 2012
2. We drap element Y drop it on the same date (19th October 2012)
3. Visually indicate that elements are 'connected' on the calendar
4. Save the pair of elements to the DB

Framework: Ruby on Rails 3.2.8, jQuery-1.8.1, fullcalendar.js 1.5.4

Comment: Are you only talking about 2 elements - drop 1 and then drop the other, and once the second is dropped on the same day, then automatically save? Or drop multiple elements onto the same day (as many as you want) and then click a Save button to save to DB?

Comment: First one, once the second is dropped on the same day then automatically save the object.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a non-standard field in the FullCalendar Event called something like `linkedto`. For event A, this will contain the event ID of Event B that it is linked to, and vice versa.
You make the elements you want to drop onto the Fullcalendar draggable and droppable. Once an element is dropped onto a day (using the Fullcalendar drop callback), you search through the FullCalendar events in memory (`clientEvents`) for an Event on that day.
If none is found, a new Event (call it A) is created on that day using the details from the drop callback.
If an event is found, a new Event is created (call it B) with a `linkedto` of the linked event ID (A.id), and the linked event's `linkedto` field is updated with the new Event ID (B.id).
Once Event B has been created, save the two Events back to the server with an ajax post (making sure all the details of the events are saved including the `linkedto` details).

Not sure how you want to visually link the two events. Would the pair of events sharing a color unique for every day of the month suffice? You could have a preset array of colors (1 to 31) for every day of the month, and set the `backgroundColor` of the pair of events to that color when creating them.